# Apps script -- Print specified range X time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to specify how many time I want the same range printed.

I already got a working script outputting the range to a HTML window but then I must hit the print button and specify the number of copies.

I'd like to be able to create those copies within the document so I could just print the whole thing.

I can't figure out where to start...

Any advice would be truly appreciated.

Thx

Sébastien

[Add printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY24U.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I already got a working script out putting the range to a HTML window but then I must hit the print button and specify the number of copies.` and `I'd like to be able to create those copies within the document so I could just print the whole thing.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Printing X (based on data present in the sheet) copies of the range but without further intervention from the user

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I've just added a printscreen in the original post... hopefully this would help clarify what I'm trying to do

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample image. Unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot manage the print condition. So as a workaround, from your sample image, in that case, how about creating the temporal Spreadsheet including the sheets copying the number of times that you want to copy? This can be achieved by Google Apps Script. By this, you can print all number of sheets by printing only one time. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggest but with Slides. I can't find a way to print this file (Slides) directly from the script within my Sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.